# Linux system clock frequency adjustment (BeagleBone)

Tags: clock, beagleboneblack, ntp

Running a BeagleBone Black with a Debian distro, and I need to use ntp to set time since timesyncd causes jumps in system time. The system clock is slow enough so that ntp errors out after a few seconds. The system clock is slow by about 3.18 seconds every minute - WAY beyond the 500ppm that ntp can deal with.
The ntptime man page hints at a -f option to set a frequency offset, but the effect seems to be limited to the +/- 500ppm range.

Is there a way to adjust the system clock tick so that it's close enough for ntp to work?